# setting executable path in mac for terraform

Tags: terraform

I know this is maybe a silly question but I am trying to export my terraform path into my linux path.

My terraform executable sits in a terraform folder under /usr/local/terraform.

I therefore did `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/terraform/terraform`

However, When i try and do terraform (going straight into terminal and type in terraform)it doesnt run. Only when I cd to usr/local/terraform and do a ./terraform then the executable runs.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: [`PATH` should be a list of *directories*](http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html), not *executables*.

Answer (score 46):

Just copy your terraform binary and place it in /usr/local/bin/

```
sudo mv terraform /usr/local/bin
```

You can now access terraform from your terminal from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your `PATH` should list the directory the executable is in, not the executable itself:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/terraform/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/terraform terraform
```

And then:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score -4):

## Quick Installation using `Homebrew`

check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYzBueRW25s)

or

steps below

#### `Step 1:`

Open https://brew.sh/

[image]

**Copy** the **URL** that showed in the **above screenshot**

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

**Paste** copied **URL** in the **terminal** and hit return/enter key

Once you **have done** with **Homebrew installation** follow **Step 2:**

#### `Step 2:` **Download terraform** from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html

**extract** downloaded **zip terraform file**

Now you will have one filename `terraform` on downloaded folder

**For instance**

`/Users/username/downloads/terraform`

#### `Step 3:`

Open a `terminal`

cd: change directory to `/Users/username/downloads/terraform`

#### `Step 4:`

**run** `brew install terraform` in the **terminal**